# Halachic basis for opposing erection of a giant statute of Jesus in Israel

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, avodah-zarah, christianity, current-events

According to [JewishIsrael.com](http://jewishisrael.ning.com/profiles/blogs/cast-a-giant-jesus-over-israel?xg_source=msg_mes_network) an Arab Christian group plans to build a giant statute of Jesus on Har Kedumin (Mt. Precipice) near Nazareth on Jewish National Fund land.  The Minister of Tourism, Uzi Landau, supports the construction project as a big draw for Christian tourists. What halachic issues does this raise?  How are those issues affected by the fact that Christianity's beliefs are considered idolatry for Jews but not necessarily for non-Jews?

Comment: What does JNF say about it?  (I know that's not the main issue here; just curious.)

Comment: Assuming that the statue is not the direct object of prayer, is it any different from any other church, status, or symbol of Christianity?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I believe that the article said that the JNF is all for it.

Comment: Ugh.  If that report is correct (and I'd want to verify it with a second source), that's revolting. :-(

Answer (score 4):

The Torah says numerous times ופסיליהם תשרפון באש, e.g. דברים פרק ז, especially in the context on entering the land of Israel.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  You can make your answer better (and more valuable for less-well-informed readers) if you translate the phrases, briefly explain them, and cite the sources.